# C# ComboBox items from an array

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I've searched for answers to this for a while, but none seem to match my problem exactly.

I have a window in which I've created a `ComboBox`. Then in my code, I've created an array:

```
public string[] myList = new[] { "Item 1", "Item 2" };
```

Now I want to make those items the options in the `ComboBox` dropdown. Most of what I found suggests using `DataSource` and `DataBind`, but only `DataContext` is actually available.

I'm sure there's some previous step I'm missing, but I'm still pretty new to this so I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: You need to specify which UI toolkit you are using. WPF? WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those answers that you found are for Winforms and you seem to be using WPF. They both have a `ComboBox` control, but they are actually a completely different controls with different properties. Try this (let's say you call it `ComboBox1`):

```
ComboBox1.ItemsSource = myList;
```

However, you usually need IDs for your items so you can use them when the user selects an item. To do that, you need to bind the `ComboBox` to a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`, like this:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, string>{
           {100, "Eggplant"},
           {102, "Onion"},
           {300, "Potato"},
           {105, "Tomato"},
           {200, "Zuccini"}
};
ComboBox1.ItemsSource = data;
ComboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
ComboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
```

Now when a user selects "Onion" for example, you will get 102 by using:

```
int selected = (int)ComboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Note: Your `ComboBox1` in XAML must have no items, otherwise you will get an error.

If you prefer to keep the items in XAML instead of code-behind, there is no equivalent to the `SelectedValuePath` property, but you can simulate it using the `Tag` property like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Eggplant" Tag="100" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Onion" Tag="102" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Potato" Tag="300" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Tomato" Tag="105" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Zuccini" Tag="200" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub If you read my answer carefully, you probably would realize that I answered for the array in the very first paragraph and code snippet. Then in the second paragraph, I explained why you'd want a `Dictionary` instead of an array. It was accepted because it did answer the question, and went beyond to providing a better alternative with a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try putting ID's with mapped to each member of the string list. It will work.